# Sencha Touch 2: Build in Production

Tags: sencha-touch-2

My app works well in development and no error during building of production. When I access the production build it says:

Error evaluating http://www.sentsa.com/build/cp/production/app.js with message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'setMasked' of undefined www.sentsa.com:9
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://www.sentsa.com/build/cp/production/cache.appcache
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache NoUpdate event

setMasked dont give me a warning in chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ref for the object you're calling setMasked on.  We've had problems when we've specified our own custom selector ie using paneltype or button type.  It works OK locally but fails in the production build.  The answer was to create our own xtype which had a paneltype in the config and this worked.

```
Ext.define('ux.form.PhoneTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'phonetabpanel',
    config: {
        paneltype: null
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Okay i will try to do this.